# My own SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code is.

```
$newModel = "INSERT INTO models (id," . 
    " firstname," .
    " lastname," .
    " email," .
    " password," .
    " group," .
    " phone," .
    " timeofday," .
    " dayofweek," .
    " address," .
    " city," .
    " state," .
    " zip," .
    " gender," .
    " hair," .
    " eye," .
    " birthday," .
    " birthmonth," .
    " birthyear," .
    " bustshirt," .
    " cup," .
    " waist," .
    " hips," .
    " waist," .
    " hips," .
    " weight," .
    " inches," .
    " dressjacket," .
    " workxp," .
    " twitter," .
    " facebook," .
    " joindate," .
    " instagram," .
    " imdb," .
    " parentid," .
    " error) VALUES (".
    PrepSQL($modelid) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($firstname) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($lastname) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($email) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($password) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($group) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($phone) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($timeofday) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($dayofweek) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($address) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($city) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($state) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($zip) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($gender) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($hair) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($eyes) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($bday) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($bmonth) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($byear) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($bust) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($cup) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($waist) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($hips) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($weight) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($height) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($dressjacket) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($workxp) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($twitter) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($facebook) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($joindate) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($instagram) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($imdb) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($parentid) . ", " .
    PrepSQL($error) . ")";

mysql_query($newModel) or die(mysql_error());
```

Its Shooting out an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'group, phone, timeofday, dayofweek, address, city, state, zip,
>   gender, hair, eye' at line 1

Comment: That code is frightening! :)

Comment: just echo $newModel before query and print here, Y r u concating simple string

Comment: Remember `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: @mukund so I could highlight all the rows of text and have it tell me how many variables at the bottom of Sublime Text 2.

Comment: @Patashu What do you suggest?

Comment: Do I even want to know what `PrepSQL` is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html).  You must wrap it in backticks:

```
`group`,
phone
```

etc.

Answer (score 4):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword and happens to be the name of your column. To avoid syntax error, you need to escape it using backtick. eg,

```
`group`
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the column name to which is not a reserved keyword to avoid problem from occurring again.

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)